# how to save images in sqlite and display it?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, download

I have a database , the database contents are the name , address , image ( varchar ) and the images folder . I 've parser ( using json ) and stored in a sqlite , whether the image can be downloaded to sqlite ? and I also wanted to present it in an application ? how to do it ?
please let me know :(

Answer (score 1):

Putting image in sqlite is bad practice.
You should store img as file and put the path to file with img to sqlite.

Comment: Do you have a source/explanation for this? I'd like to learn more about why it's considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

serialize them to internal storage and save the paths as ordinary string values. But if your images are dynamic (loaded from web sources) I would better save their links and use LruCache http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a table with BLOB datatype 
     String SQL_TABLE = "create table "
      + TABLE_MESSAGE + "(" + "id"
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
      + "name"  + " text not null, "
      + address     + " text not null, " 
      + image   + " BLOB);";


      to store image into this you have to convert it to bytes like so:

     public static byte[] makeByte(Bitmap bitmap) {

     if (bitmap == null) {
     return null;
     } else {
     byte[] b = null;
     try {
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, byteArrayOutputStream);
     b = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return b;
     }
     }
```

after the get byte then you can save into the database like you save or update any other field.
then you can recreate the image using this function and add to ImageView

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromByte(byte[] pByte){
    if (pByte == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(pByte, 0, pByte.length);

    return bmp;
    }
```

pass the above function the bytes you stored in database, this will return a bitmap that can        be set on imageview
        exmaple Bitmap img = getBitmapFromByte(byteData);